# Need help setting a minimum number of characters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, minimum

I am trying to set a minimum of 5 characters for a password field and it is not working. Ever time I put in 0 or 1 characters it works but the challenge fails to work when entering 2 to 5 characters. Can someone take a look at what I have and tell me where I am going wrong?

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Password</legend>
      <label>Create Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id"password"><br /><br />
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword">
   </fieldset><br />  




if (document.sample.password.value <=5) {
         alert("Password must contain 5 characters.");
         document.sample.password.select();
         document.sample.password.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
         return true;    // leave now 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Password</legend>
      <label>Create Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br /><br />
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword">
   </fieldset><br />  




if (document.getElementById('password').length<=5) {
         alert("Password must contain 5 characters.");
         document.getElementById('password').select();
         document.getElementById('password').style.backgroundColor="yellow";
         return true;    // leave now 
}
```

Note the added `=` in the HTML for `id"password"`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately it still isn't working. Here is what I have now.

Comment: if (document.getElementById('password').length<=5) {
         alert("Password must contain 5 characters.");
         document.getElementById("password").select();
         document.getElementById("password").style.backgroundColor="yellow";
         return true;    // leave now 
}

Comment: <fieldset>
    <legend>Password</legend>
      <label>Create Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br /><br />
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword">
   </fieldset><br /